# Is there any special reason behind the formula of radix complements? My concern is with whether memorizing the formula is the only way to remember it

Tags: digital-logic

I am recently studying the concepts of diminished radix complement and radix complement. This is a simple question. I am aware of the formulas. I just want to know if there is a special reasoning behind why they are made that way. Yes, they are used to represent negative numbers and perform logical operations but when it comes to learning I kind of remember things better if they have some sort of associated reason why formulas are constructed that way. But I do fully understand if there is no derivation and the concept was made out of convenience.

Yes I also know the formula is short. I am just asking out of curiosity.

The formula I am referring to is

r's Complement

r's C = r^n - N

(r - 1)'s Complement

(r - 1)'s C = r^n - r^-m - N

r - radix

n - number of digits

m - fractional part

N - original digit

Comment: I am not sure which formulas you are describing. Maybe you could enter or link to one of the formulas? It might lead to a better answer if more people can understand which formulas you are asking about.

Comment: AndriodV11, @mkeith is saying what I wanted to say. There are so many teaching methods, so many phrases, that it really helps us orient ourselves if you provide concrete samples to make your points. There are very, very good reasons most of the time for various formats. Sometimes, it's more a theoretical interest (balanced trinary might be such a beast) and sometimes it is very practical for very specific reasons (such as twos complement.) None of us want to go google phrases and sort through the results to see if we can figure out your writing. Better you just show us.

Comment: I added the formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think of say a bike odometer or a customer counter with for exampne 4 digits, you know it will count from 0000 to 9999 and then rolls over back to 0000, so they show the same count every 10000 counts because there is only four digits.

As these will only count upwards, and it happens to read a count of 5555, and you want to subtract 1, you need to go upwards 9999 counts before the reading is 5554.

Thus, -1 is same as +9999, which equals the highest number that can be displayed. Extending that, -2 equals +9998.

The same applies in binary, for a four bit value, -1 is same as +1111 (15 in decimal), or largest representable 4-bit number. Extending that, -2 is +1110 in binary or 14 in decimal.

That is what your formulas describe in a generalized mathematical fashion.

Comment: You explained it so well. But how does the r^-m in Diminished Radix Complement or r-1 complement work, just asking.